# jHispter Elasticsearch issue after adding any custom entity

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'countryServiceImpl' defined in file [E:\tms-ws\TransportManagement\target\classes\com\baltransport\tms\app\v1\service\impl\CountryServiceImpl.class]: 
  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'countrySearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
[org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: 
    Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Failed to build mapping for country:country
    at org.springframework. ...
```

Getting this exception jHispter Elasticsearch issue after adding any custom entity .

It works perfectly fine first time (with default jdl)

Comment: What are the parameters of the constructor of the class: `CountryServiceImpl.java`? This is failing when your entity is mapped to an Elasticsearch object I believe. Are you sure that you need Elasticsearch in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can try:

1. Delete db and create again.
2. Import  your jdl, with the news changes, maybe new entity.
3. Run elasticsearch in docker. (Find this file .yml in your project) and check if this is run correctly (localhost:9200)
4. Run your app (monolith or microservices)

Regards

Comment: Working fine on local .

Comment: For me just restarting ElasticSearch is enough

Answer (score 1):

you can try to delete the indexes in elasticsearch directly from the url.
Supposing you index is called "user" you can do the

DELETE /indexname