# Jhipster, Problem with spring boot (BeanCreationException) and elasticsearch linked to (NumberKeyedRepository)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jhipster

I'm new to using jhipster and elasticsearch for some time, when I import my entities an error appears

```
        ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Mao\Projets\Mobili\target\classes\ci\mobili\mobili\service\impl\FileServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
            at ci.mobili.mobili.MobiliApp.main(MobiliApp.java:63) [classes/:?]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans 5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:182) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:497) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to execute action
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.execute(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1223) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.executeWithAcknowledge(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1228) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:196) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexWithSettings(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1438) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexIfNotCreated(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1423) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:177) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.createIndex(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:96) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:87) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository.(NumberKeyedRepository.java:36) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:497) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            ... 22 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
            at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
            at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.executeRequest(JestHttpClient.java:133) ~[jest-5.3.4.jar:?]
            at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:67) ~[jest-5.3.4.jar:?]
            at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:60) ~[jest-5.3.4.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.execute(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1215) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.executeWithAcknowledge(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1228) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:196) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexWithSettings(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1438) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexIfNotCreated(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1423) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:177) ~[spring-data-jest-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.createIndex(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:96) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:87) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository.(NumberKeyedRepository.java:36) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:497) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
            ... 22 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  17:31 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-13T15:29:17Z
    [INFO] -------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is because u don't run **elasticsearch server.** U can run this with docker, (the file .yml) and later run your app.

Or try this answer :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068893/8436194